# Error SQL71567 in Visual Studio Database Projects. Create temporal table on non primary Filegroup result in a build error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, temp-tables, visual-studio-2022, dacpac

I’m using Visual Studio 2022 to develop, build and deploy DataBase Projects. The project we are working on has many filegroups, so we are not using the primary.

In this context, creating temporary tables result in a build error:

> Error SQL71567: Filegroup: [TestFilegroup] cannot be specified on Table: [dbo].[TestTable_History] when there is the clustered Index:
> [dbo].[TestTable_History].[ix_TestTable_History] on the table.

I also reported the issue to microsoft, but so far I have not received an answer (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-sql71567-in-visual-studio-database-projects/1637959)

Does anyone had same error or know how to workaround it?

**Example code:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [TestID]    INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [StartDate] DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START NOT NULL,  
    [EndDate]   DATETIME2 GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL, 
    PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (StartDate, EndDate),  
    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TestID]) ON [TestFilegroup], 
) ON [TestFilegroup]
WITH (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = dbo.TestTable_History));
```

Comment: The table's `on filegroup` is redundant, and could not possibly be different, due to: _If the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint creates a clustered index, the data pages for the table are stored in the same filegroup as the index._ Ref: [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql)

Comment: Likewise, for the history table, _If the history table does not exists, the system generates a new history table matching the schema of the current table in the same filegroup as the current table, creating a link between the two tables and enables the system to record the history of each record in the current table in the history table._

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, thanks for your comments. The above script is working fine in SQL Server. My problem is that it isn't working in my Visual Studio projects, because the build fail ([example repo](https://github.com/RafBorrelli/SqlServerError-HistoryTableOnNonPrimaryFG)).
The feature you described is exactly what I'm trying to achieve via SSDT, to have the system generates a new history table when it doesn't exists.

Comment: I resolved a similar issue where the history table was erroring due to a typo in a type. It is resolvable in Visual Studio by removing the WITH... line, saving, rebuilding etc. Its not an exact science but removing the history table definition then readding it seemed to resolve the mismatch.